# Unicode degree symbol not visible in command prompt?

Tags: java, windows, unicode, command-line, command-prompt

I'm working on a small program that includes temperature displays. I want to have it display the degree symbol(°) next to the temperature, and the current code does that properly when I run it inside of my IDE(IntelliJ), but as soon as I try to run it from the command line, it isn't visible.

The print statement is written as follows:

```
System.out.println("The current temperature is " + currentTemp +"\u00B0");
```

[Again, it displays properly in IntelliJ,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSb3A.png) but [when I try to run it from a default command prompt, it doesn't have the degree symbol.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNd12.png)

I'm using Java 14.0.1, Windows 10 version 1909. Let me know if any other information would help

Comment: What exactly is `currentTemp`? Post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking for debugging assistance.

Comment: Possibly, this Q/A [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016189/windows-10-cli-utf-8-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016189/windows-10-cli-utf-8-encoding) may solve your problem?

Comment: Your code [runs successfully in IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/5hBs9k).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream( System.out, true );
out.println("The current temperature is "+currentTemp  + "\u00B0" + "C" );
```

The ouput :

[image]

Comment: Why is that any better?